# Integration, Lebesgue and counting measure

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Could you help me with the following exercise?

Consider $X=Y=[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure $m$ on $X$ and counting measure $\omega$ on $Y$.

Let $f:X \times Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $f(x,y)=  \begin{cases} 1, \ \ \ \ \ \text{for}  \ x =y \\  0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \text{elsewhere}\end{cases}$

Could you tell me why $\int_X f(\cdot, y) \ d m=0$ and $\int_Y f(x, \cdot) d\omega = 1$?

Comment: These integrals reduce to $m(\{y\})$ and $\omega(\{x\})$. I let you finish.

Comment: Right. $0$ and $1$ follow straight from the definition of Lebesgue and counting measures. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For a fixed $y$, $\int_X f(x,y)\mathrm d\lambda(x)=\lambda(\{y\})$ because $f(x,y)=\chi_{\{y\}}(x)$, where $\chi$ denotes the characteristic function. The Lebesgue measure of a singleton is $0$, hence $\int_X f(x,y)\mathrm d\lambda(x)=0$.

A similar computation gives $\int_Y f(x,y)\mathrm d\mu(y)=\mu(\{x\})=1$, where $\mu$ is the counting measure.

This show that Fubini's theorem is not necessarily valid when one of the measures is not $\sigma$-finite (here the counting measure on the uncountable set $[0,1]$).